# How can I disable compiler warnings in Eclipse on a file specific basis?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

In my Eclipse project are a handful of generated .java files that I need to use for SQLJ and I can't move to a separate project (due to Administrative Overhead). These files are also regularly regenerated so editing them is unfortunately out.

Unfortunately these files generate a few hundred java compiler warnings which drown out the useful warnings I get on files that I actually can edit.

Is there any way in Eclipse to say Ignore all the warnings of a file-by-file basis? Or can I block out a specific sub-directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "problems" view in eclipse can be filtered; I always have it set to "on selected element and its children only". Granted, this is more of a work-around, but it lessens the impact of having the files in the same project. (Note that even if you must have them in the same project, you can keep them in a separate source folder).

Edit: To configure the filters, find the icon with a downward arrow with tooltip "View Menu" on the top right of the problems view. Click it, and then click "configure contents".

Comment: I've tried filtering the problems view to a working set. The "selected elements and its children only" is pretty sweet actually!

Comment: Please clarify how to filter the problems view.  It's not obvious.

Comment: Cute but insufficient.  You can't hide both warnings containing "Dead code" and "raw type".  You can't show all warnings except in folder X.

Answer (score 26):

Ensure the files are under the `gen` folder, the typical home for all generated .java files. Then in the project properties, under **Java Build Path**, set **Ignore optional compile problems** for that folder to **Yes**.

If your project structure requires your files be in a folder other than `gen`, add that folder to the Java Build Path so that you can enable ignoring optional compile problems for it.

Comment: Very useful. This seems to be what the OP asked for, and I needed the same.

Comment: this is the answer to the question

Comment: I believe this is the answer to the OP's question as well.  To use this approach with a Maven project, I send all generated files to src/main/gen and use Edwards solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answers as it can be a best practice (as an example, Android currently uses gen source directory)

Comment: I don't have said option under Java Build Path.  What version of Eclipse are we talking about?

Comment: @FlorianF Eclicpse 4.2.1, Android Developer Tools 23.0.2.1259578. Make sure you are on the **Source** tab. If you expand **Android/gen** you should see an **Ignore optional compile problems** node in the tree, which you can select, and then click **Toggle**.

Comment: I see.  I am using MyEclipse which is based on Eclipse 3.7.  Maybe that's why.  Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 12):

[@SuppressWarning](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) [annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)?

Per, Stephen's comment, you can find the "Per project compiler settings option here"

Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Errors/Warnings

Enable project specific settings

[image]

Comment: Good too. The problem is that the SQLJ files are in the same project and many of the warnings are useful to have for other files. I need a file specific settings...

Comment: The Javadoc for `@SuppressWarning` isn't very helpful to understand how to use it. It lacks examples.

Comment: The Eclipse documentation about `@SuppressWarning` is more detailed. See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to add `@SuppressWarning(...)` annotations to the source code.

Another way would be to move the troublesome code to a separate Eclipse project and use per-project compiler settings.

**EDIT**

Surely, you can partition your code into multiple projects with the appropriate inter-project dependencies?

If not, I'd say you are out of realistic options.  (But if you want some unrealistic ones, you could post-process the generated code to add the annotations, hack the Eclipse Java compiler to implement per-file suppression, hack the Eclipse "Problems" view to implement per-file/directory filtering of errors, etc, etc.)

Comment: +1 "per-project compiler settings." New thing learnt!!

Comment: Yea that is is good. The problem is that the SQLJ files are regularly newly generated (Whenever someone changes the SQL). So all the @SuppressWarning(all) disappear then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide warnings on a class or on a method, see the Eclipse documentation on the [`@SuppressWarnings` annotation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm) or [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)

Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void foo() {
    String s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the files are regularly generated. So each time I'd have to add the @SuppressWarning by hand to tens of files.