# Blackberry navigationClick invoke problems

Tags: blackberry, navigation, click, invoke

Eclipse keeps telling me about invoke problems. This is the message i get as can be seen below. Please help me resolve this problem. What code should i put to get rid of the invoke problem. thanks.

```
Warning!: method 'parsepack.xmlparsing.navigationClick(int,int)' not invoked.
Warning!: method 'parsepack.xmlparsing.insert(String,int)' not invoked.
```

here is the method `navigationClick()`

```java
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{
    try
    {
        //navigate here to another screen   
        ui.pushScreen(new ResultScreen()); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Exception:-  : navigationClick() "+e.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

here is the method `insert()`

```java
public void insert(String toInsert, int index) 
{
    listElements.addElement(toInsert);
}
```

here is the class **xmlparsing.java**

```java
package parsepack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class xmlparsing extends UiApplication implements ListFieldCallback, FieldChangeListener
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        xmlparsing app = new xmlparsing();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }


    public long mycolor ;
    Connection _connectionthread;
    private static ListField _list;
    private static Vector listElements = new Vector();
    public MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
    VerticalFieldManager mainManager;
    VerticalFieldManager subManager;
    UiApplication ui = UiApplication.getUiApplication();


    public  xmlparsing()
    {
        super();
        pushScreen(screen);

        final Bitmap backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("blackbackground.png");

        mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR )
        {

            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight(),backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);

                super.paint(graphics);
            }

        };

        subManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR )
        {
            protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
            {
                int displayWidth = Display.getWidth();
                int displayHeight = Display.getHeight();

                super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
                setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
            }
        };


        screen.add(mainManager);

        _list = new ListField()

        {

            public void paint(Graphics graphics)

            {
                graphics.setColor((int) mycolor);
                super.paint(graphics);

            }

        };
        mycolor = 0x00FFFFFF;
        _list.invalidate();
        _list.setEmptyString("* Feeds Not Available *", DrawStyle.HCENTER);
        _list.setRowHeight(50);
        _list.setCallback(this);
        mainManager.add(subManager);
        listElements.removeAllElements();
        _connectionthread = new Connection();
        _connectionthread.start();
    }


    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
    {
        try
        {
            //navigate here to another screen
            ui.pushScreen(new ResultScreen());                
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception:-  : navigationClick() "+e.toString());                
        }

        return true;
    }



    private class Connection extends Thread
    {
        public Connection()
        {
            super();
        }

        public void run() {
            Document doc;
            StreamConnection conn = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try {

                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("http://imforchange.org/international-movement-for-change/testing/data.xml"+";deviceside=true");

                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                docBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true);
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                docBuilder.isValidating();
                is = conn.openInputStream();
                doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("eventName");
                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node textNode = list.item(i).getFirstChild();
                    listElements.addElement(textNode.getNodeValue());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    try { 
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    try { 
                        conn.close(); 
                    }
                    catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }    
            } 
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    _list.setSize(listElements.size());
                    subManager.add(_list);
                    screen.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }

    }


    public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w)
    {
        String tes = (String)listElements.elementAt(index);
        int yPos = 0+y;
        g.drawLine(0, yPos, w, yPos);
        g.drawText(tes, 5, 15+y, 0, w);
    }


    public Object get(ListField list, int index)
    {
        return listElements.elementAt(index);
    }
    public int indexOfList(ListField list, String prefix, int string)
    {
        return listElements.indexOf(prefix, string);
    }
    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField list)
    {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }
    public void insert(String toInsert, int index) {
        listElements.addElement(toInsert);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {


    }
}
```

**ResultScreen.java**

```java
package parsepack;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class ResultScreen extends MainScreen {

    public ResultScreen() {
        LabelField resultLabel = new LabelField("Result: ");  
        add(resultLabel);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Is there any button or some UI on which you are calling `navigationOnClick()` method.

Comment: where you are using this navigation click method?

Comment: Can you just post your xmlparsing class here?  I don't really want to download a RAR file to look at this.  Thanks.

Comment: i updated it, i put the entire class here. thanks guys for wanting to help. :-)

Comment: No problem.  For future reference, you should probably check out [Jon Skeet's blog post on tips for asking questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).  Also, remember that if you get an answer that helps you, or solves your problem, click on the arrow and/or checkmark next to it, to say that the suggestion helped, or that your problem is solved (or both).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, those messages you're seeing are **warnings**, not **errors**.  Warnings are not always a problem, but sometimes they are.  In this case, I think that at least the first message is a problem, so you'll want to fix it.

1) First, the `navigationClick()` method.  The compiler is telling you that you have an implementation for the method `navigationClick()` that is never called from any of your code, or by the BlackBerry OS infrastructure.  That's probably not what you want.  Normally, `navigationClick()` is a method that you override in a class you write that `extends` one of the BlackBerry `Field` classes.  For example, a `ButtonField` subclass.  `navigationClick()` will be called, in that case, when the button is clicked.

But, you placed your `navigationClick()` method in the main `UIApplication` subclass.  That's not what you want.  You need that method to `override` the `navigationClick()` method in a field class.  I'm not sure which field you want to have call this method when the user clicks.  But, for example, you might do something like this:

```java
_list = new ListField()
{
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setColor((int) mycolor);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
    {
        try
        {
            //navigate here to another screen
            ui.pushScreen(new ResultScreen());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception:-  : navigationClick() "+e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

That would make `navigationClick()` get called when your list is clicked, and it will get rid of the warning.

2) Regarding the warning about `insert()`, that's just because you're not using it anywhere.  It look like you've added that method to allow code outside the `xmlparsing` class to be able to insert items into the list.  Maybe that's what you want, but you just haven't yet written the other code to use that method.   I see you having at least a few choices:

1. remove or comment out the `insert()` method until you need it.  this will get rid of the warning.
2. add some more code that **does** use this method.
3. ignore the warning, just making sure you understand that the warning is telling you that you have some code that is not (yet) necessary, since it's unused
4. you can suppress warnings in Java programs, [by doing this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm), or [this, in the Eclipse preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624776/119114), if you know the warning is not a problem, and you don't want excessive warnings to hide real problems.  I *normally* don't recommend this.  Usually, it's better to fix the warning, than to hide it.

Comment: wow. what a beautifully expressed answer. you are blessed. thanks alottt nate. i'll try it and give u feedback.

Comment: @ejobity, happy to help.  Thanks for posting your code, and describing your problem well.