# How to suppress error for missing `throws`

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, throws

Is there a way to get Eclipse to suppress errors for a missing `throws` declaration when throwing exceptions within methods?

If you are to build and run something without explicitly specifying `throws`, it will unwind to the `main` method and crash the program (which is what I want in this particular case). There are certain exceptions that do it, such as `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException`, which allows you to throw it without needing to specify `throws`.

Comment: Can't you just add a throws-declaration to your main method? (I don't have Eclipse installed on this computer, so I can't test it myself, unfortunately...)

Comment: Not when the call hierarchy is really deep. At the point of this exception, I'd have to add over 13 throws declarations, which isn't something I want to do.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3624776/38055) - the options pane shown there seems to have a lot of options for various errors and warnings. Maybe there's something there?

Comment: Sounds like it's a checked exception, which you must either surround with a try/catch or add in the throws clause. Since, it is a syntax error you cannot suppress it. What you can do is catch it and throw a new unchecked exception, which doesn't require that throws clause.

Comment: `UncheckedExceptions`, as far as I know, are useless with `throw` because they don't actually do anything (they're mainly for documentation purposes). `RuntimeException` is what I wanted.

Comment: @Qix: Errors and runtime exceptions are collectively known as unchecked exceptions.  Please have a read of the article linked to by yshavit.

Comment: @GregKopff, Ah my mistake. I read another SO question wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse isn't doing anything special here; the issue is in the Java code itself. Your two best options are to change the method's signature to include the `throws`, or to catch the exception and rethrow it as a RuntimeException (or subclass of RuntimeException).

```
try {
    doWhatever();
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new SomeRuntimeException(e);
}
```

...where SomeException is or extends Exception (but not RuntimeException), and SomeRuntimeException is or extends RuntimeException.

For more info, check out the section in Sun's Java tutorials on [checked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: +1 `RuntimeException` did it! Thank you. I was creating my own exception in this case so it was as easy as changing `extends Exception` to `extends RuntimeException`.