# Eclipse: Remove warnings like "Unnecessary cast from Object to Object"

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4.0.9 MVC application using JSPs as the view technology and Maven 3.2.5 for the build management. And I use Eclipse 4.4.1 for development and Tomcat 7.0.57 for running the application.

In the JSPs I want to use the EL expression `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to reference the current request path. But Eclipse gives me the error:

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type`

I added the following Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the error disappears, but now I get some new types of warnings. Wherever I use the EL expression above, Eclipse says:

`The declared exception IOException is not actually thrown by the method _elExpression7505() from type __2F_myproject_2F_src_2F_main_2F_webapp_2F_WEB_2D_INF_2F_views_2F_page_2E_jsp`

And everywhere I use Spring's `form:label` tag it tells me:

`Unnecessary cast from Object to Object`

Does anybody know how to get rid of these warnings? Do I have to use other Maven dependencies? (I've also included javax.servlet-api 3.0.1, jstl 1.2 and many more)

**Edit:** I do not want to globally ignore this type of warnings for all Java files. To me, this would rather be a workaround than a real solution.

Comment: I generally just ignore the random warnings Eclipse shows you.  It works fine at run time ;)

Comment: Yes, on runtime there are no problems. It's just ugly having these warnings in Eclipse.

Comment: are these warnings just redundant or are they actually _wrong_? If wrong, then it would be an Eclipse issue. I get the same errors, and I just tried pulling out the generated JSP java classes from the server which is presumably where the warning is generated - workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\ETL4ECN\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp - but I had no luck pinning it down.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, Eclipse has a place to edit warning/error preferences:

```
Project Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings
```

There's a nice search box which you can use to track down the error/warning setting you'd like to edit (for example you could look for "Unnecessary cast").
In the dropdown to the right of the entry that shows up, you can then select `Ignore`. Hit "Apply", rebuild the project and you should have gotten rid of the warnings you wanted gone.

You would have to set the following warnings to "ignore":

- `Unnecessary cast or 'instanceof' operation`
- `Unnecessary declaration of thrown exception`

See [this help page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm) for reference.

**Edit:**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296709/2154149) answer on Stackoverflow, you can include folders from being checked for warnings. I haven't tested this myself, so this is a long shot.

Comment: This solution would imply, that these kind of warnings are also ignored for all Java files. And since I have to follow some very restrictive company-wide guidlines, this is not the best option for me.

Comment: @SebastianS. Do you have the jars in a folder?

Comment: I wonder why there isn't a fix yet, since JSPs are not a bleeding edge technology and I would assume many people must have seen this warnings.

Comment: I have the typical tomcat jars in its lib directory.

Comment: @SebastianS. Does that directory belong to the Eclipse project, so that it is in the project build path? Can you not access the directory using Eclipse?

Comment: No, it does not belong to the project and is not on the build path. Only the Maven dependencies (scope: provided) are. To my understanding this would be enough.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know a solution to that particular problem, but I'm going to edit my answer and add a general solution that I've found digging on Stackoverflow. I'd suggest you to edit your question and mention that you need to keep your .java files intact.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your JSP, you can include the following:

```
<%! @SuppressWarnings("cast") %>
```

This will prevent eclipse from showing the eclipse "unnecessary cast object to object" warning.